# How to set system clock as 32 MHz internal RC Oscillator in AVR?

Tags: avr

I am working on some project where I need to enable 32Mhz internal oscillator for **ATXMEGA128A1** controller.Someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

The system clock can be changed to the 32MHz internal oscillator by setting the  `SCLKSEL` bits (Bit 2:0 in the XMEGA's control register `CTRL`) to `001` as described in detail in the [XMEGA A Manual](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8077.pdf) section 7.9.1.

Changing the clock source at runtime is a protected operation on XMEGA devices which has to be enabled following the configuration change protection procedure described in manual section 3.12 by writing a signature value `0xD8` to the configuration change protection register `CCP` before being allowed to change the clock source within the next 4 instruction cycles. The definition of signature values and `CCP` register layout can be found in manual section 3.14.1.

> **3.12 Configuration Change Protection**
>
> System critical I/O register settings are protected from accidental
>   modification. The SPM instruction is protected from accidental
>   execution, and the LPM instruction is protected when reading the fuses
>   and signature row. This is handled globally by the configuration
>   change protection (CCP) register. Changes to the protected I/O
>   registers or bits, or execution of protected instructions, are only
>   possible after the CPU writes a signature to the CCP register. The
>   different signatures are described in the register description.
>
> **3.12.1 Sequence for write operation to protected I/O registers**
>
> 1. The application code writes the signature that enable change of protected I/O registers to the CCP register.
> 2. Within four instruction cycles, the application code must write the appropriate data to the protected register. Most protected registers
>      also contain a write enable/change enable bit. This bit must be
>      written to one in the same operation as the data are written. The
>      protected change is immediately disabled if the CPU performs write
>      operations to the I/O register or data memory or if the SPM, LPM, or
>      SLEEP instruction is executed.